# Use ~ in std::process::Command

Tags: rust, command, directory-structure

I am trying to use std::process::Command to run webdrivers programmatically installed at
`$HOME/.webdrivers`. I don't want users to have to add the directory to their path, so I was hoping to be able to use something like

```rust
let geckodriver = Command::new("~/.webdrivers/geckodriver")
        .stdout(Stdio::null())
        .stderr(Stdio::null())
        .spawn()?;
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I'm getting the error for the executable not being there.

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Could not start geckodriver: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/lib.rs:49:10
```

Anything helps!

Comment: that the shell that replace `~` with home, try to invoke bash instead `"bash -c ~/.webdrivers/geckodriver"`

Comment: I still get the No such file or directory error, but ~/.webdrivers/geckodriver works from the terminal :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tilde expansion is a feature of the shell (bash, etc.) - the OS facilities that `std::process::Command` use do not expand tildes. So you will have to do it yourself.

Get the `HOME` envvar using [`std::env::var_os`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.var_os.html), convert it to a `Path`, then `join` your executable path onto that.

Answer (score 3):

As stargateur mentioned `~` is expanded by the shell. `bash` is a shell that can be used to perform the expansion. Instead of spawning `geckodriver` directly spawn bash to spawn `geckodriver`

```
let geckodriver = Command::new("bash")
        .arg("-c")
        .arg("~/.webdrivers/geckodriver")
        .stdout(Stdio::null())
        .stderr(Stdio::null())
        .spawn()?;
```

*Beware:*
Packing the args into the string passed to `Command::new("bash -c ~/.webdrivers/geckodriver")` will not work since that will look for an executable with filename `bash -c ~/.webdrivers/geckodriver` (with spaces in the filename).